# Pyspark dataframe write to sql server datetime field value gets changed

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing the data from spark (pyspark) to SQL Server and I am observing that the value of time in datetime fields are changing. It appears that some timezone value gets added.

How can I keep the value as-is.

appreciate your help.

Comment: Aaron, Thanks for your response.  The date and time fields are 2 different fields in the csv file and this is converted to datetime using to_timestamp(). 
The Master node and SQL Server have the same server times, they are different machines. However,  the worker nodes ( 2 of them ) are having time which is 4 hrs ahead.  Strangely this 4hrs is the difference I am seeing. 
when the dataframe is queried, the value is as expected. Is the jdbc driver which is doing the conversion.  I am using mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre8.jar for writing to SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
```